# How can I log variables to a txt file?

Tags: 8, debugging

In Drupal 7 I use devel's  drupal_debug() or its alias dd() to log a variable to a drupal_debug.txt in the site's temp directory.

In the Drupal 8 version of devel this function has disappeared. It seems to be replaced by [DevelDumperManagerInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/src%21DevelDumperManagerInterface.php/function/DevelDumperManagerInterface%3A%3Adebug/8.x-1.x) 
But it is not clear to me how it used.

How can I log variables to a txt file in Drupal 8?

Comment: How about printing them in a message? `drupal_set_message(var_dump($variable), 'warning');`

Comment: In the D8 devel module drupal_debug() as been replaced by the devel.dumper service, but the alias dd() is still there and now points to the service.

Comment: Also printing it to the logs is possible with \Drupal::logger('crimi')->notice($value); but dd() can be nice in some cases. Actually I managed to get it working when I figured out I was disabling the devel module constantly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DevelDumperManagerInterface interface is implemented by [DevelDumperManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/src%21DevelDumperManager.php/class/DevelDumperManager/8.x-1.x). This class is in turn used as a service, '[devel.dumper](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.services.yml/8.x-1.x)'.

One way to use this function would be the following:

```
$ddumper = \Drupal::service('devel.dumper');
$ddumper->debug($variable_name, NULL, 'default');
```

That would log the variable `$variable_name` to `drupal_debug.txt` located in the temp folder directory. See [DevelDumperManager::debug()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/src%21DevelDumperManager.php/function/DevelDumperManager%3A%3Adebug/8.x-1.x) docs for more information.

Good luck!

Comment: What exactly does this code do? does it dump the variables somewhere on the page when the code runs?

Comment: @NoSssweat : It logs a variable to a drupal_debug.txt in the temp folder directory. See https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/src%21DevelDumperManager.php/function/DevelDumperManager%3A%3Adebug/8.x-1.x

Comment: I think I am missing something here. I get the error exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'You have requested a non-existent service. I run this code from within a migrate plugin, so the devel functions may not be availabe at that point ...

Comment: In that case, please update your OP to add this important information. I am gonna take a look at this and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: First question: Is the devel module installed and functioning in your Drupal instance? For example, what do you get for this command: drupal container:debug | grep debug.dumper ? Or for this one (using drush): drush ev "\Drupal::service('devel.dumper');"

Comment: ah! found it. I did a config import each time before running the migration. This disabled the devel module ... that is why I got the ServiceNotFoundError . thanks for the pointers